# react constructor var undefined (cannot read of undefined)

Tags: reactjs, class, ecmascript-6, constructor

New to react and am stuck on the below; I have tried writing it a few different ways and the outcome always trips up on the first dictation of '`fruit`' being `undefined`, within `constructor(props)`. I am simply trying to create a working dropdown select, capturing the selected value in react.

**File one, /App.js**

```
import React from 'react'
import {ReactExample} from './index'
import './App.css'

class BooksApp extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { fruit: props.item.fruit }; <-------- errors
  }

  handleChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({ [event.target.name]: event.target.value });
  }

  saveItem = () => {
    const item = {};
    item.fruit = this.state.fruit;
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="app">
        /* ...other HTML etc*/
                    <ol className="books-grid">
                      <li>
                        <div className="book">
                          <div className="book-top">
                            <div className="book-cover" style={{ width: 128, height: 193, backgroundImage: 'url("workingAPIURL")' }}></div>
                            <div className="book-shelf-changer">
                   
                                <ReactExample name="fruit" value={this.state.fruit} handleChange={this.handleChange} />

                            </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </li></ol></div>
        /* ...other HTML etc*/

}

export default BooksApp
```

**Second file, index.js**

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import App from './App'
import './index.css'

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'))

export const ReactExample = ({ name, value, handleChange }) => (
    <select name={name} value={value} onChange={handleChange}>
        <option value="move" disabled>Move to...</option>
        <option value="currentlyReading">Currently Reading</option>
        <option value="wantToRead">Want to Read</option>
        <option value="read">Read</option>
        <option value="none">None</option>
  </select>
  )
```

**Error:**
[image]

Comment: The error means that `props.item` doesn't exist, i.e. the component isn't passed a value for the `item` prop. And that's indeed the case: `<App />`. You are not setting `item`. How to fix that depends on how you want the component to work: Is it valid to *not* pass `item`? If yes then you have to check whether it's set before you access it. If it's not valid then you actually have to pass some data.

Answer (score 0):

You have not defined any props for the App component in index.js. This can be done this way:

```js
<App item={ fruit: 'yourValue' }/>
```

If you don't want to have the value passed as props, you can simply initialize state in constructor like this:

```js
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { fruit: 'yourValue' };
  }
```

I would also suggest naming components and their default imports the same way. It is a little confusing that you have BooksApp imported as App in index.js.

Comment: Still a bit confused with it's implementation. So, I am replacing my option tags with app item in your first suggesting?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by your question. I would suggest to look into official React docs to see how to work with inputs and forms: https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html.